# pierdo un cero al redondear un float con precision de 2 en java

Tags: java, float, redondeo

estoy manejando cifras usando float, para redondear utilizo la instrucción:

BigDecimal red= new BigDecimal(numero).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

compruebo que me devuelve lo siguiente:

"sale red:" 102655,10

como trabajo con float, al hacer el return hago la conversión a float:
red.floatValue();

pero antes compruebo lo que saca por pantalla, que es lo siguiente:

"convierto a float:" 25452.1

pierde el 0, solo pasa obviamente con los números que al redondear terminan en 0. hay alguna manera de solucionar esto, probé usando la instrucción decimal.format pero me luego al transformarlo a float me daba error.

muchas gracias a todos.

---

mi objeto son todos campos float, y al hacer operaciones con ellos, redondeo usando este metodo:

public static float redondeo(float num) {

```
    BigDecimal red = new BigDecimal(num)
                                .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

    System.out.println("redondeo bigDecimal" + red);  // 2244.10
    System.out.println("redondeo float " + red.floatValue()); //2244.1
   
   return red.floatValue();
}
```

Comment: Puedes añadir un ejemplo de tu código para poder tener una mejor comprensión de tu problema.

Comment: Ese código, ponlo en tu pregunta

Comment: No pierdes nada, porque ese cero no vale nada. Tecnicamente el problema ahora lo tienes en la manera en que imprimes en valor, y no a la hora de calcularlo. Prueba a imprimirlo así: `System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", red.floatValue()));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Double  formatearDecimales(Double numero, Integer numeroDecimales) {
return Math.round(numero * Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales)) / Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales);
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es un cálculo que multiplica el número a redondear por 10 elevado a la cantidad de decimales que deseas obtener de redondeo y a este resultado se le divide el mismo número a redondear multiplicado por 10 elevado igualmente a la cantidad de decimales que deseas obtener, posteriormente se hace el redondeo a todo este cálculo matematico

Esta función te permite formatear cualquier número, a la cantidad de decimales que desees.

Referencia:
https://programandoointentandolo.com/2017/11/limitar-numero-decimales-double-float-java.html

En esta página te explican unas cuantas maneras de hacerlo, pero esta es una forma general y te sirve para cualquier lenguaje, respetando por supuesto la sintaxis de cada lenguaje.

Incorpora esta función a tu código y adapta tu código para que puedas usarla en el, aquí se trabaja con double, pero perfectamente puedes cambiar a float

Comment: He probado tu código, y el problema del OP persiste: a la hora de imprimir en consola, muestra solo un número. Por qué es eso? Porque si tienes dos decimales y el segundo es un cero, **no vale nada** así que el print lo omite. Para evitar que eso sea así debes imprimirlo indicando el formato específico con el que deseas imprimirlo, por ejemplo `System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", 0.20f));` imprimirá 0.20 en consola, mientras que `System.out.println(0.20f)` imprimirá 0.2