# ¿Por qué no imprime todos los valores del tipo flotante en java?

Tags: java

Estoy colocando el siguiente código en java para imprimir una variable de tipo flotante, pero al obtener el resultado, observo que no imprime todos los valores declarados en la variable.

```
public class Caso{
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        float pi = 3.14159265359f;

        String resultado = String.format("%f - Decimales: %1$.2f", pi);
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }
}
```

Y el resultado que imprime es:

```
3.141593 - Decimales: 3.14
```

Estuve buscando en varias páginas, pero todas se enfocan en como limitar el número de decimales como %.2f, %.3f, etc.

¿Alguien sabe por qué es?

Comment: Puedes usar un número alto en el formato, ejemplo: "%.15f - Decimales: %1$.15f", de manera que imprires todos los decimales y algunos más.

Comment: Entra aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414023/pierdo-un-cero-al-redondear-un-float-con-precision-de-2-en-java

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias hechas, pero es posible que haya generado mal la pregunta, en si lo que quiero saber es ¿por qué se pierden los demás decimales? Si es un tema con el tipo de dato **float** o una propiedad del método **String.format**.

Comment: Tu problema es en el String.format, donde le estás pasando como parámetros el `float pi` como `%f`, pero luego le estás diciendo que te de el número como `%1$.2f`, indicando que, del valor obtenido, sacar sólo 2 decimales. Si quieres más decimales, cambia el 2 por otro valor mayor.

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez te sugiero que agregues este comentario como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Cordial saludo prueba de esta manera:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

        Double pi = (Double) 3.14159265359;

        String resultado = String.valueOf(pi);
        System.out.println(resultado);

    }
```

[image: como vez muestra todos los decimales]

Comment: Pero no explicas porqué el OP tiene el problema planteado y de qué modo tu solución lo resuelve.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es en el String.format, donde le estás pasando como parámetros el float pi como %f, pero luego le estás diciendo que te de el número como %1$.2f, indicando que, del valor obtenido, sacar sólo 2 decimales. Si quieres más decimales, cambia el 2 por otro valor mayor.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    
    float pi = 3.14159265359f;

    String resultado = String.format("%f - Decimales: %1$.11f", pi);
    System.out.println(resultado);
}
```

El problema de esto es que, cuanto mayor sea el valor del número delante del f, mayor dispersión del dato. En el caso de `11f`, la consola devuelve `3,14159274101`.

En cambio, si ponemos un valor menor, por ejemplo; `5f`, `3,14159`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, pero creo que aún nadie ha entendido mi pregunta. La cuestión es, ¿por qué en la impresión del %f, se limita a imprimir solo 6 decimales? cuando en la declaración de la variable he puesto hasta 11 decimales. Entiendo que colocar %1$.11f me imprime los demás valores, pero el enfoque de mi pregunta está en el solitario %f

Comment: Supongo que será el valor por defecto que tiene el método.

Comment: Es posible que así sea, aunque aún me falta profundizar sobre el cálculo de los valores flotantes. Pero me llama la atención tu comentario, porque en varias páginas donde he buscado la explicación del metodo, siempre en la parte del flotante, ponen como ejemplo la impresión de 6 valores decimales.

Comment: Puede ser, no estoy seguro de ello pero tiene sentido, de que a partir de 6 valores decimales, el error es tan pequeño que no provoca ningún tipo de problema en el cálculo.