# como tomar solo 2 decimales en una variable en c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Mi problema consiste en lo siguiente, tengo este código que registra registra a un usuario en una app en Windows form para medir progresos etc., el problema radica en que cuando introduzco un valor de peso o altura del tipo flotante al introducir yo los 2 decimales en la base de datos guarda 12,

que debería hacer ? modificar mi tabla en SqlServer o modificar el código de registro?

Anexo el código que hice:

**Sql Tabla Users**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserWeight](
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Weight] [float] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [date] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**C#**

```
private void Btn_NewUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                register.CrearUsuarios(
                    TxtUsuario.Text,
                    TxtNombre.Text,
                    TxtApellido.Text,
                    Convert.ToBoolean(cmbsexos.SelectedValue),
                    Convert.ToInt32(cmbSomato.SelectedValue),
                    Convert.ToInt32(TxtEdad.Text),
                    float.Parse(txtPeso.Text),
                    float.Parse(TxtAltura.Text));

                UserModel user = new UserModel();


                MessageBox.Show("Registro Exitoso");
                this.Close();
                
                Login login = new Login();
                login.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + error.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414023/pierdo-un-cero-al-redondear-un-float-con-precision-de-2-en-java/414232#414232 entra aqui y llevate la idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes poner el valor en la base de datos de tipo decimal como el siguiente codigo, el campo ITBIS lo coloco como decimal y asi solo tengo que enviarle los datos desde visual studio y la bd se encarga del resto

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ingreso](
[idingreso] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[idtrabajador] [int] NULL,
[idproveedor] [int] NULL,
[fecha] [date] NULL,
[tipo_comprovante] [varchar](20) NULL,
[Serie] [varchar](4) NULL,
[correlativo] [varchar](7) NULL,
[ITBIS] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
[estado] [varchar](7) NULL,
```

[image: Como puedes ver el campo ITBIS tiene los valores en decimal]

EL campo ITBIS el valor ingresado esta en decimal

Comment: Excelente solución lo implementare apenas pueda!

Answer (score 0):

Actualización: Pude hacer el redondeo en C# pero el valor que llega a la DB siempre me marca 12 decimales, ahora supongo que debería modificar mi Cache de usuarios para cambiar como se obtienen los valores de la DB, aunque me gustaría leer sus sugerencias

**Anexo la solución al redondeo**

```
            float Peso = float.Parse(txtPeso.Text);
            float Altura = float.Parse(TxtAltura.Text);
            Math.Round(Peso, 2);
            Math.Round(Altura, 2);
```

Comment: publicaste una pregunta en la parte de respuesta. Podrias evitar colocar codigo que no se necesite leer para resolver un redondeo

Comment: @RamiroBarone Anotado y corregido thx por el dato.

Comment: Los tipos de coma flotante en una bd se representan como longitud,precision  donde longitud es la cantidad de cifras del número y precisión la cantidad de decimales, ej number(3,2) crea un campo numérico de 3 cifras con dos decimales, debes ver como se hace esto en tu gestor,

Comment: Averigua que tipo de datos en sqlserver es el que te hace falta